# Order results by two differents fields in entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have advertisement table, i want to order it first by special, then order by last added, but special ads has end date, so i want to order special ads that its date is still

This is my code

```
List<S_Advertisements> moduleItems = db.S_Advertisements
       .Include(x => x.S_AdvertisementsImages)
       .Where(x => x.CatId == pureId && x.IsActive == true)
       .OrderByDescending(x => x.IsSpecial)
       .ThenByDescending(x => x.AdId).ToList();
```

I want to know if Entity Framework will let me do something like that :

```
List<S_Advertisements> moduleItems = db.S_Advertisements
       .Include(x => x.S_AdvertisementsImages)
       .Where(x => x.CatId == pureId && x.IsActive == true)
       .OrderByDescending(x => x.IsSpecial.Where(x => x.DateSpecialEnd > DateTime.Now))
       .ThenByDescending(x => x.AdId).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude but your question being "I want to know if Entity Framework will let me do something like that", and given you've already written the code, why don't you press F5 and check the result? Then if it's not the result you expected, please ask a question.

Comment: What's the type of IsSpecial by the way? The name would suggest it's a Boolean, and if that's the case "x.IsSpecial.Where()" won't compile.

Comment: its already intellisense error, so it will surly gives error during compile !,

Comment: my question show the idea that i want to apply, but i dont know how to apply it, so i gives an example, and i know that its incorrect intellisense

Comment: First code snippet looks good to me: it's ordered by two column and filter based on your condition. I don't understand what else you are trying to achieve. I invite you to rephrase the question.

Comment: I have advertisement table, i want to order it first by special, then order by last added, but special ads has end date, so i want to order special ads that its date is still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be :

```
DateTime dtn = Datetime.Now;
var moduleItems = db.S_Advertisements
   .Include(x => x.S_AdvertisementsImages)
   .Where(x => x.CatId == pureId && x.IsActive == true)
   .Select( x => new {
        o = x,
        c = x.DateSpecialEnd > dtn ? 0 : 1 // not a boolean but an order info
   })
   .OrderByDescending(z => z.c)
   .ThenByDescending(z => z.o.AdId).ToList();
```

same as in sql: view for calculating the field, then order the view.

Comment: @AhmadAlaa sorry, it should be better now

Comment: I think i must now make view model to just take S_Advertisements object, i will try and feedback, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The placement of the where clause doesn't affect ordering. Whether you order by `IsSpecial` or by `IsSpecial.Where(...)` the order would be the same, regardless. That's pretty much why what you're looking for doesn't exist: there's no need for it to.